# Converting curl to python: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to convert `curl` command to python script.

Here is the curl command which works great in command line:

```
curl -v -H 'X-Api-Key:123456789' https://synthetics.newrelic.com/synthetics/api/v3/monitors -G -d 'limit=100'
```

Here is the python script:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'X-Api-Key': '123456789'
}

data = {
    'limit': '100'
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://synthetics.newrelic.com/synthetics/api/v3/monitors', headers=headers, data=data)


print(response.content)
```

The output of the script is:

```
{"code":415,"message":"HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"}
```

I also tried to dump the data while passing it to the request using `json.dump(data)` which didn't help (Got the same error).

What am i doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: The `-G` flag to curl makes it a `GET` request, not a `POST` request.

Comment: you can convert it on portal: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @furas I actually wrote the script using that website.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you! It's indeed supposed to be GET and not POST. Now it works. Don't know why that website converted the command as POST. Next time i will write it by myself ;)

Comment: [curl.trillworks.com](https://curl.trillworks.com) uses `curlconverter`, and it was not parsing `-G`. I have fixed it, and now it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Dainis. Do you know what should i do with data in curl such as `-d 'x=5'` for example? How should is convert it to python? I've tried many variations, So far with no success. Also `curlconverter` didn't help.

Comment: Do you have a cURL command to refer to? `curl http://localhost:3000 -d 'x=5'` is similar to `response = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/', data={'x':'5'})`. Both send a POST request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and  a `x=5` in the payload body. Python sends its own user agent and also `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header, meaning that the requests are not identical.

Comment: @Dainis, Please see here: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/get-synthetic-all-monitors-in-python/81122. I got an answer regarding the issue.